# Uploading To A MySQLi Server A Base64 Image Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

So after trying a few methods of uploading a Base64 Image String to the database I have noticed that after uploading some spaces and "next lines" were missing.
If I have a Base64 String of an image in Android Studio, how do I upload and download it to a PHP server without changing the original?

Comment: JFYI, there is no such thing like "mysqli server"

Comment: thanks for informing, changed it.